# Getting error mysqlclient not install after the installation?

Tags: python, mysql, django

Getting the following error when I am trying the 
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install MySQL client?

I install MySQL and MySQL client and configure the setting.py file in Django project, And now when I am going to migrate a project 
it is throwing following error.

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install MySQL client?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djangodb',
        'USER': 'ROOT',
        'PASSWORD':'',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'3306',
    }
}
```

It is giving the following error

Did you install MySQL client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is download and install wheel file
Download the wheel file from the following link

 https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient

 select the file which supports to your operating system. if you dont now which is support try one by one

 you download the file `mysqlclient‑1.4.2‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` which support `windows 64-bit os`

 now you need to use the following command 

 pip install path_of_you_file

 `pip install mysqlclient‑1.4.2‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 0):

Are you Installed mysql-python package ??

I think this error is for python-mysql is not installed in system,Please use this command.

```
pip install mysql-python
```

or

```
sudo pip install mysql-python
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows run the following command as administrator in the command prompt:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 0):

Try install mysql-client by going to [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) and you will find many mysql-client wheels.

- Download the first one #do not change the name of the file,,
- open command prompt,
- use cd to go to the directory where your wheel has been installed,
- then use pip install (name of file) #use .whl as well

if it doesn't work, download the second one and repeat the process, if that doesn't work as well, keep on downloading until I guarantee you that at least one of them would be installed in your computer